# Jupiter server stopped to start

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupiter Notebooks, using VSCode and Python extension (on Windows).
Everything was running properly until today. There were no changes or modifications from my side.
What I normally did:

1. First I opened VSCode, than opened existing notebook.
2. Then I saw a small window that said: "Connecting to Jupiter kernel"
   and the notebook opened properly.

Today Jupiter server stopped to initialize and the small window disappeared. When I tried to run a cell, it said that "notebook" is not installed.
It's very strange as it was all working yesterday perfectly. Then it stopped working without any action from my side.
Then I have updated VSCode and installed notebook.
However, when I try to load the Jupiter notebook, it says *"Couldn't find kernel 'Python 3.7.0 64-bit' that the notebook was created with. Using the current interpreter."* I did not update Python and it is the same  3.7.0 64-bit version. I couldn't google anything similar.

Two questions:

1. What have happened and why? I have not changed or updated anything or uninstalled anything. Why all of a sudden Jupiter Notebooks stopped working?
2. What does the message about kernel ("Couldn't find kernel ...) means? Why?
   It is super weird.

Who did it? Am I being hacked by somebody messing with my computer?

Comment: Try running jupyter-notebook (with a hyphen). This should normally be the same as jupyter notebook (with a space), but if there’s any difference, the version with the hyphen is the ‘real’ launcher, and the other one wraps that.

Comment: @user136555 -When you type "pip show ipykernel" in the VS Code terminal using "python3.7", does it output "ipykernel" information? It is recommended that you reinstall the "python" extension and "Jupyter" extension and then reload VS Code.